# Coldfusion CFINVOKE parameter not working?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfinvoke

I want to invoke a cfc file on my webserver, but I always get the error: The required parameter [UserID] was not provided.

Coldfusion code:

```
<CFINVOKE component="changeTree" method="getTreeWidth" returnVariable="httpTreeWidth">
<cfinvokeargument name="UserID" value="#checklogin.UserID#">
</CFINVOKE>
```

changeTree.cfc:

```
<CFFUNCTION name="getTreeWidth">
<CFPARAM name="UserID" required="true">
...
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you're on ColdFusion 10 you can simplify your invoke to `<cfset changeTree = new changeTree()><cfset httpTreeWidth = changeTree.getTreeWidth(checklogin.UserID)>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In changeTree.cfc, it's suppposed to be `<cfargument name="UserID" required="true">` not `<cfparam>`.